# How do I add a "class" to a ChoiceField in Django?

Tags: django

I have a `ChoiceField` in my Django Form:

```
gender = forms.ChoiceField(label='', choices=GENDER)
```

I'd like to add a `class` `attr` to the field so I can style it. Something like the following usually works:

```
forms.Field(label="Display name",help_text='',widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'wideInput'}))
```

But this doesn't work for the ChoiceField, I get the following error:

> TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'attrs'

What `widget` should I use in order to add a class to my ChoiceField?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

I had a quick read of https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/forms/widgets/

which rabbited on about widgets - apparently they are

> Django’s representation of a HTML input element. The widget handles the rendering of the HTML

and then each form field is tied to a widget - have a read of:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/forms/fields/#built-in-fields

for the ChoiceField, the defaultWidget is "Select" (as noted in the above link). Ok, knowing the right  widget, to add the class i just needed:

```
widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class':'regDropDown'})
```

so that my final line ended up reading:

```
gender = ChoiceField(label='', choices=SEX, widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class':'regDropDown'}))
```

Huzzah!

Comment: You should be able to accept your own answer after a certain time period

Answer (score 8):

the ChoiceField use the forms.Select widget

```
forms.Select(attrs={"name": "select_0","class": "form-control"})
```